# How to read an image from firebase in tablecell on ios (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, storage

I'm trying to read some images stored in my firebase storage.

How is this possible to be achieve? I'm using a UITable View with Cell.

I've added a UIUmage in the Cell.

then I 'm trying to call the image from the storage via:

```
cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "gs://mybundefirebase.appspot.com")
```

without success

here is the full function, the textlabel appear correctly, but not the image.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row];
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center;
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "gs://mybundefirebase.appspot.com")

    return cell!
}
```

any help ... will be incredible ! I'm having lot of trouble with that !!

Thanks guys !!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Firebase: FirebaseStorageUI that you import like this

```
import FirebaseStorageUI
```

and user like this:

```
let urlToData = "gs://mybundefirebase.appspot.com" + "/" + folderOfImage + "/" + imageNameOnStorage 

let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: urlToData) //ctreates reference to image in storage

let placeholderImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder") //placeholder if wanted

imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage) //will set your image for you
```

This will also cache the image in the memory for you so you won't have to make to many requests to the storage as well if you plan to retrieve the same image somewhere else in your app

EDIT: in your case you can have the urlToData be equal to:

```
let urlToData = "gs://mybundefirebase.appspot.com/a-chair-bl.jpg"
```

This would work if the name of the image on storage is `a-chair-bl.jpg` and it is placed in the `root` folder

EDIT2: you can call the above code in `cellForRowAt` but I would not suggest this. You should do it in your `PostCell` where you should create a function for it and just call the function from `cellForRowAt`

EDIT3: Also to access `FirebaseStorageUI` you need to add this to your `podfile` and run `pod install`

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
```

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for this.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

in my database, I have different post ( in the screenshot below call "Videos") with different information.

I'd like, for the post to be able to assign an image from the firebase storage.

Example: in the screenshot below still, in the Databse, Videos, 1, image I've added the value "gs://bundleid.appspot.com/a-chair-bl.jpg" to call the image.

I'd like then to call the image in the table Cell,

At the moment the title is being call only.

Comment: Where should I place your code to make it work ? In the same function ? it doesnt seem to work :(

Thanks a lto for all your time, I really appreciate !

Comment: well for a good architecture the image you want to assign to the post should be for example in a new folder in storage called 'PostImages' for example and there have your image that maybe have a predefined name like the postid it is part of like this 'postIdImage'

Comment: Um, let me try al of this and I come back to you :)

The Idea is that I could add in the firebase database new "Video" so it will be dynamic. I suppose for that I need to keep the code  as let urlToData = "gs://mybundefirebase.appspot.com" + "/" + folderOfImage + "/" + imageNameOnStorage and it will fetch the link I've added in the dabatase from my screenshot ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Seems I can not find FirebaseStorageUI in swift :(

Comment: yes ... if you want it to be dynamic you should use that structure since you can pass parameters to match with what you want to retrieve

Comment: add this to your podfile  'pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134682/discussion-between-tibewww-and-john).

Comment: Thanks John,

Im having those errors: 'Use of unresovled identifierd'imageNameOnStorage' and  'Use of unresovled identifierd 'imageView'

Do you ahve any idea why :( ?